# Magento 1.7.0.2 - Subtotal and grand total doubled in cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

A few customers have complained that they are getting subtotal and grand total prices that are double of what they should be.
After some tests, I've found that when a user adds a product to cart, go to checkout, then changes his mind and removes the item from the cart - the next time he will add a product to the cart, the subtotal and grand total prices will get doubled. It happened only in IE and Firefox, not in Chrome.

I've found this post:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/227560/P0/

I've checked the DB table sales_flat_quote_address and saw there were quote ids that had more than one shipping and billing address.

I implemented the solution that is shown in this post:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/227560/P15/#t393997

and the price is no longer getting doubled in the situation I described above.

The problem is that since this fix I still get occasionally a complaint from customers about the price being doubled and I see the same situation in the DB table sales_flat_quote_address, but I can't reproduce this issue so I don't know when it happens.

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: i have simillar problem. total show twice. I have also double entry of shipping address. can you tell me how you solved for double address entry in sales_flat_quote_address i see link posted by you but its give me 404 page not found.